# What does SAGA stand for?

Tags: transactions, saga, long-running-processes

I know that A saga is a sequence of local transactions where each transaction updates data within a single service. The first transaction is initiated by an external request corresponding to the system operation, and then each subsequent step is triggered by the completion of the previous one.

**but What does SAGA stand for?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't an acronym, so it's not capitalized

A Saga is just a story

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga

When applied to computer science, it's still just a sequence of actions